# L.geoJson() - Error: Bounds are not valid

Tags: leaflet, geojson, geocoding, ajax

I am iterating through an array of zipcodes and passing each to Mapbox Geocoding API. With every iteration, on success, I pass to L.geojson().  After the last iteration I call map.fitBounds(jsonLayer).

Then this error:

> ...Uncaught Error: Bounds are not valid

Here is my full code:

```
var zipList = ["90210", "03103", "11206", "79109"];

function findMe(zipList) {
    var listLength = zipList.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
        var myRequest = "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" + zipList[i] + ".json?access_token=" + L.mapbox.accessToken + "&limit=1";
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: myRequest,
            success: (function (data) {
                jsonLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
                    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                });
            })
        })
    }
    map.fitBounds(jsonLayer);
};
```

Does this have something to do with Ajax and asynchronous?  What can I do to avoid this error and fit map to comprehensive marker set?

--

Edit: I have also tried pushing lat and long coordinates to an array before calling map.fitBounds(markerArray); Same error.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    markerArray.push(L.marker([feature.geometry.coordinates[1], feature.geometry.coordinates[0]]));
}
```

Comment: Several methods to get markers featuregroup bounds can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845614/zoom-to-fit-all-markers-in-mapbox-or-leaflet

Comment: Thank u @NettaB I am trying methods from this page.  Could you advise as to why message 'Bounds are not valid'?

Comment: From my experience there's a difference between marker and polygon featuregroup. The best method n my opinion is `var bounds = L.latLngBounds(markerArray);
map.fitBounds(bounds);`

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at the [leaflet GeoJSON](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) example, and implement the `pointToLayer` method in order to add your markers properly.
You are sending several ajax requests and recreating the geoJSON group in each ajax call. I think that this approach would help :

```
var zipList = ["90210", "03103", "11206", "79109"];
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
  radius: 8,
  fillColor: "#ff7800",
  color: "#000",
  weight: 1,
  opacity: 1,
  fillOpacity: 0.8
};
function findMe(zipList) {
    var listLength = zipList.length;
    var featuresData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
        var myRequest = "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" + zipList[i] + ".json?access_token=" + L.mapbox.accessToken + "&limit=1";
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: myRequest,
            success: (function (data) {
                featuresData.push(data)                
            })
        })
    }
    var jsonLayer = L.geoJson(featuresData, {
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
            }
        });
    map.fitBounds(jsonLayer.getBounds());
};
```